# How can I remove empty strings from a list that is a value of a specific key in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python

Given that I'm new in Python and my background is in social sciences I I'll try to do my best to explain the problem and I thank you in advance for the valuable help!

I have a list of dictionaries storing information of online recipes. For the specific key `['ingredients']`, I have a list of strings as value. I would like to clean the list by deleting the empty strings.

Here is an example of how my data looks like:

```
data = [{'title': 'Simple Enchiladas Verdes',
         'prep_time': '15 min',
         'cook_time': '30 min',
         'ingredients': ['', 'chicken', '','','','tomato sauce']
        },
        {...}, {...}]
```

The result that I would like to obtain for the key 'ingredients' is:

```
data = [{'title': 'Simple Enchiladas Verdes',
         'prep_time': '15 min',
         'cook_time': '30 min',
         'ingredients': ['chicken','tomato sauce']
        },
        {...}, {...}]
```

I have tried different codes:

---

```
for dct in data:
    for lst in dct['ingredients']:
        for element in lst:
            if element == '':
                dct['ingredients'] = lst.remove(element)
```

---

```
for dct in current_dict:
    for lst in dct['ingredients']:
        dct['ingredients'] = list(filter(lambda x: x!=''))
```

---

```
for dct in data:
    for lst in dct['ingredients']:
        for x in lst:
            if x == "":
                dct['ingredients'] = lst.remove(x)
```

---

But none of them solve my problem.

Comment: You also need to pass the list to filter ... to `filter()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite close. You just need to do:

```
for dct in data:
    dct['ingredients'] = list(filter(lambda x: x != '', dct['ingredients']))
```

What happens here is, for every dictionary `dct` in `data`, you take `dct['ingredients']` and pass it to through the `filter` function, with the predicate `lambda x: x != ''`. The result is an "iterable", something from where you can get one element at a time. You then use `list` on that to obtain a proper list, and assign the result back to `dct['ingredients']` to replace the original list.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way using [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
for dct in data:
    dct['ingredients'] = list(filter(None, dct['ingredients']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
for dct in data:
    dct['ingredients'] = [el for el in dct['ingredients'] if el != '']
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def removeEmtyItems(liste, copyliste):
for item  in copyliste:
    if item=="":
        liste.remove(item)

return liste


for dict in data:
    for value in dict.values():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            copyliste=list(value)
            removeEmtyItems(value, copyliste)

print(data)
```

or just

```
for dct in data:
     dct['ingredients'] = list(filter(lambda x: x != '', dct['ingredients']))
```